# Know what is causing “Warning: setState(…): Cannot update during an existing state transition…”, but not sure where the cause should be moved to

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am running into this error. Numerous SO questions on it, but still having difficulty figuring out where I need to move the call to the action to get around the error.

> Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to componentWillMount.

I have two sibling containers that I am trying to share a Redux store between: update the store in one via an action so that I can use it another one. One container is a search/filter `<BasicQuerySearch />`box and the other container is a list of results `<BasicQueryPositionList />`.

The results are narrowed down as the user types. As the field is reduced a `<div>` below the search box states how many current results there are. That number is determined in the list of results container where it should be passed through the action, update the store, so I can call it in the search box container. The update is happening, but not without this error polluting the browser console.

I know what the cause of the error is: updating the store in `render()` with:

```
getCount(n) {
    this.props.posCount(n.length);
}
```

It is just unclear to me where to call it outside of the `render()` that will permit updating after the container has mounted. Thus, `componentDidMount()`) wouldn't work because it won't update after the container has mounted and the user has started typing.

Here is the parent container and the two siblings:

```
// parent container
// ./query.js

import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

// imports for the basic query when selected
import BasicQueryPositionList from './bq_position_list';
import BasicQuerySearch from './bq_search';

// imports for the advanced query when selected
// .... these are to come

import { getQuery, clearQuery } from '../../actions/results';

class Query extends Component {

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.props.clearQuery();
    }

    // render the main element of the container
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='panel panel-default'>
                <div className='panel-heading'>
                    <h4><strong>Compensation Data Results Query</strong></h4>
                </div>

                    <div className='panel-body'>
                    {!this.props.pos_list
                        ?
                        (
                            <div>Loading...</div>
                        )
                        :
                        this.props.pos_list.length == 1
                            ?
                            (
                                <h5>The query is currently not available for this survey.</h5>
                            )
                            :
                            (
                                <div>
                                    <BasicQuerySearch />

                                    <hr />

                                    <BasicQueryPositionList />
                                </div>
                            )
                    }

                    </div>
            </div>
        ); 
    }
}

// map the state in the Redux store to props
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        pos_list: state.results.pos_list,
    }
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps, { clearQuery })(Query);
```

---

```
// sibling #1 container
// ./bq_search.js

import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { searchTerm } from '../../actions/results';

class BasicQuerySearch extends Component {

    // Declare the state "term"
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            term: '',
        };
    }

    // When someone enters into the search box, it narrows down 
    // the list of positions; also filters out speciality chars
    onInputChange(term) {
        var cleanString = term.replace(/([`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:''",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]+)/g, "");
        term = cleanString.toLowerCase();
        if (!term) {
            term = ''
        }
        this.setState({ term });
        this.props.searchTerm(term);
    }

    // renders the search box that filters down the list of positions
    render() {

        const { pos_count } = this.props;

        console.log(pos_count);

        return (
            <div>
                <input 
                    className='form-control' 
                    placeholder='Enter Keyword or Position Code' 
                    value={this.state.term}
                    onInput={event => this.onInputChange(event.target.value)}
                />
                <h5><b>{pos_count}</b> {pos_count == 1 ? 'Position' : 'Positions'} Found</h5>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        pos_count: state.results.pos_count,
    }
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps, { searchTerm })(BasicQuerySearch);
```

---

```
// sibling #2 container
// ./bq_position_list.js
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { clearQuery, getQuery, posCount } from '../../actions/results';

class BasicQueryPostionList extends Component {

    // renders the options and also filters down the results
    renderPositionsOptions(pos) {

        // generate the <option> list
        return _.map(pos, p => {
            var option = p.FinalCode + ' - ' + p.PosTitle
            return (
                <option
                    key={p.FinalCode}
                    value={p.FinalCode}
                >
                    {option}
                </option>
            );
        })
    }

    // filter down the list of positions
    filterPositions(term, pos) {
        const filtered_items = _.filter(pos, p => 
            (p.FinalCode + ' - ' + p.PosTitle).toLowerCase().match(term)
        )
        return filtered_items;
    }

    // count how many positions are in the list
    getCount(n) {
        this.props.posCount(n.length);
    }

    // renders the search box that filters down the list of positions
    render() {

        const { search_term, pos_list } = this.props;

        const filtered_positions = this.filterPositions(search_term, pos_list);

        this.getCount(filtered_positions);

        return (
            <div>
                <h4>Position:</h4>
                <select className='form-control'>
                    <option></option>
                    {this.renderPositionsOptions(filtered_positions)}
                </select>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// map the state in the Redux store to props
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        pos_list: state.results.pos_list,
        survey_id: state.results.survey_id,
        search_term: state.results.search_term
    }
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps, { clearQuery, getQuery, posCount })(BasicQueryPostionList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a more fundamental problem here with the structuring of this code. You are in a way duplicating state. The state representing the number of filtered results is really derived state from the `pos_list` itself, and you shouldn't be storing state derived from other state back into the state tree.

What I would recommend doing, is moving the `filterPositions` method out from the one component into a shared location. Then import it in both your `BasicQuerySearch` and `BasicQueryPostitionList` components and use it in their `mapStateToProps` function to get the filtered list as well as the count.

This will mean you are no longer duplicating state and also stop the above warning from happening.

The downside of this is that you will be calling the `filterPositions` function twice instead of once, but the solution for that is to look at making `filterPositions` a memoized selector (with something like the [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) library).

Answer (score 1):

why not put your code in `componentDidUpdate`

```
...

getCount(n) {
    this.props.posCount(n.length);
}

// renders the search box that filters down the list of positions
render() {

    const { search_term, pos_list } = this.props;

    const filtered_positions = this.filterPositions(search_term, pos_list);

    return (
        <div>
            <h4>Position:</h4>
            <select className='form-control'>
                <option></option>
                {this.renderPositionsOptions(filtered_positions)}
            </select>
        </div>
    );
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps , prevState){
    const { search_term, pos_list } = this.props;
    const filtered_positions = this.filterPositions(search_term, pos_list);
    this.getCount(filtered_positions);
}

...
```